# maven dependencies automatically removed from web deployment assembly in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, web-deployment

I started a web app project in eclipse, added the maven nature to ease dependencies download and management and created some files..

Each time I add a new dependency to my pom.xml (to use some specific class A) and then update the project, tomcat says it cannot load class A (although it is included in the build path and exists in the filesystem). To solve this, I add "Maven dependencies" to the project's deployment assembly.

The problem is that I need to re-add "Maven dependecies" to the project's deployment assembly each time I add a new dependency.. because it is simply removed maybe when stopping tomcat or redeploying..

Could you please explain me why maven dependencies are not automatically included it the project has the maven nature, and especially why "Maven dependecies" are removed..

Thank you